# Split partial classes into separate files

Tags: .net, visual-studio, partial-classes

I have a very basic question. In a Visual Studio project, I found two partial classes named *Startup*. The classes are in different files.

[image]

If I click on the first method (ConfigureAuth), it appears in the class file "Startup.Auth.cs". The second file appears in the class file "Startup.cs". How can I organize the classes like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use partial classes in C# to split a big class into several files. Refactoring a big class is often better but there are some legitimate reasons to have big classes.

Another use of partial classes is to allow a code generated class to be manually modified. The code generated part of the class goes into one file while the manual changes are kept in a separate file. In your case there is a single `Startup` class that are built from seperate source files handling seperate parts of the startup. Some of these files can be added by NuGet packages and using a partial class greatly simplifices how different features are included in your application.

It is quite simple to split a class into several source files using `partial`:

Assume you have a class implemented in the source file `MyClass.cs`:

```
class MyClass {

  public void MethodA() { ... }

  public void MethodB() { ... }

}
```

You can then split it into two source files. `MyClass.A.cs`:

```
partial class MyClass {

  public void MethodA() { ... }

}
```

And `MyClass.B.cs`:

```
partial class MyClass {

  public void MethodB() { ... }

}
```

So by marking the class as `partial` you are allowed to spread the contents of the class across several instances of `class` constructs. The compiler will merge them all into a single `class` definition during compilation.

You can study [the details about partial classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have a source file Startup.Auth.cs with the partial class Startup and method ConfigureAuth. What should I do now? Add another class named Startup?

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald: _What should I do now?_ I don't know. What is your problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: if I follow your instructions, I get two class files Startup.Auth.cs and Startup.cs with the same content (Startup). But I would like to have them "combined" as shown in the picture.

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald: The title of your question is _Split partial classes into separate files_ but now you ask about how to _combine_ them. That confuses me but I will try to answer how you can change a partial class into a non-partial class. You reverse the process, e.g. in your case cut all methods inside `partial class Startup` in the `Startup.Auth.cs` file and paste them inside `partial class Startup` in the `Startup.cs` file. Then remove the almost empty `Startup.Auth.cs` file. You can also remove `partial` from `class Startup` but OWIN NuGet packages will expect this class to be partial.